# In this sentence is it "you and me" or "you and I"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, coordinating-conjunctions

I tried reading online articles about this but I'm still not understanding when it is correct.

The sentence:

> 1. "Logic is not for people like **you and me**."

Is this accurate and in which context could this change to "you and I"?

If the word "logic" was replaced by an adjective would that change anything?

Comment: If the word "logic" were replaced by an adjective, it would change everything — you would no longer have a complete sentence. That said, when the personal pronoun is the subject, it is "I"; when it is the object, it is "me." As your subject is "logic," it cannot logically be replaced by an adjective. "Me" is thus the object to which "logic" applies and is therefore the correct pronoun.

Comment: The correct standard English is to use **you and me**, in your sentence, but in some dialects it's grammatical to use **you and I** there. You can find similar thing in conversations. This answer from ELL site is helpful - http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/61431/3463

Comment: @Jake Regier What if the word "gentle" was used instead of "logic"? It would not be a complete sentence?

Comment: @verve You could say, "People like you and I are not gentle" or "Gentleness is not for people like you and me," but — unless you are going for the Shakespearean approach of inventing words by ascribing them new parts of speech — you would not use an adjective in place of a noun.

Comment: Jake Regier Interesting!  I always have trouble with grammar. So in my original sentence if I use "you and I" then can I use an adjective such as "gentle"?

Comment: @verve: no. That makes no sense at all. That is absolutely not what Jake said. No, no, no.

Comment: Well, I voted to reopen this question, but it seems that my vote isn't showing up.

Comment: Here's a thread with some info that you might find useful: [Is it “I” or “me” in “Keep Tom and I/me updated”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/is-it-i-or-me-in-keep-tom-and-i-me-updated/59914#59914). Notice the excerpt from H&P CGEL page 463, examples in [23.i ].